# Getting fully_qualified_digest into yaml for deploy

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, digest

We have a GKE cluster with 4 deployments/pods that need to be updated when we deploy new code. I know it's best practice to deploy the image with the latest digest for the images we are deploying but I'm wondering if anyone knows of a better way of updating the yaml file with that digest other than manually updating it. I can get the fully_qualified_digest using:

`gcloud container images describe gcr.io/xxxx/uwsgi`

It really sucks to have to manually update yaml files with the latest digest hash each time we deploy. If someone knows a better way I'd love to hear it.

Side note: It's 2019 and Kubernetes should be able to grab the digest hash form /latest without having to explicitly define it.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: uwsgi
  name: uwsgi
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  minReadySeconds: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: uwsgi
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: certs/gcp.json
        - name: ENV
          value: prod
        image: gcr.io/xxxx/uwsgi:latest <------ needs to be fully_qualified_digest
        name: uwsgi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9040
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health/
            port: 9040
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 15
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health/
            port: 9040
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 15
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1000Mi"
            cpu: "1800m"
          limits:
            memory: "1200Mi"
            cpu: "2000m"
      hostname: uwsgi
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
status: {}
```

Comment: What prevents you from writing a small program in Python that retrieves the fully qualified digest and updates the YAML file before using it?

Comment: I'm actually in the middle of doing that right now.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of tools which will watch your Docker repository and will update things when a new image is available. The most commonly used is probably https://github.com/weaveworks/flux/. Kubernetes itself does not provide this feature as it would potentially be non-convergent.

That said, you *can* use `:latest` in a pod spec just fine. The reason to avoid it is Kubernetes won't know to restart your pods when the image changes (also cache issues but you can avoid those with an image pull policy in spec). If you don't actually want automatic deployment of new images, then what you have is fine.